# Проблема с открытием файла для чтения в C++

Tags: c++

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Делал по примеру с интернета, так как не особо разбираюсь C++.

А проблема собственно в том, что программа думает, что файл не существует, хотя он находиться в той же самой папке, что и код.

Можете помочь объяснить ошибку?

Сразу скажу, что имя файла написано корректно.

```
int file_mass(HANDLE hStdOut, int* size, int* mass)
{
    int k = 0;
    std::string line;

    std::ifstream in("rand.txt");
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        printf("1");
        system("pause");
        while (getline(in, line))
        {
            printf("2");
            system("pause");
            std::istringstream(line) >> mass[k];
            k++;
            if (k == 1499)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
        system("pause");
    }
    *size = k;
    SETING(hStdOut, size, mass);
    return 0;
}
```

Суть программы: создание массива из данных из файла

Comment: "Где код" — это не всегда текущий каталог. Даже где программа — тоже. Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу и посмотреть, что получится...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо. Как-то не додумался посмотреть где именно лежит файл. Просто привык к PyCharm, где при переносе файла из папки через сам PyCharm переносились данные и на самом пк. В VS совсем по другому